# Creating an Azure Policy preventing internet access directly from subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-policy

I want to create a Azure subscription where resources can't be created that can access the internet directly and instead need to be routed back to an on-premise appliance.

I've created the following Policy and applied it to the subscription

```
 {
"if": {
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "source": "action",
      "like": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/*"
    }
  ]
},
"then": {
  "effect": "deny"
}
```

However, it looks like internet access is still possible.  Do we need to create a custom UDRs for all subnets to route all 0.0.0.0/0 traffic back to on-prem?

BTW, in AWS creating a similar SCP was fairly straightforward:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_example-scps.html#example_scp_5

Answer (score 0):

Policy works on aliases basis so you must look for a valid aliases. `Microsoft.Network/publicIDaddress` is not one. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#aliases) for information on how to get aliases.

If you are looking for Application gateway the aliases is `Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/frontendIPConfigurations[*].publicIPAddress`

Comment: Ok and then I would just route 0.0.0.0 traffic back to to the VPN?

Comment: I realized that also your overall policy definition structure is wrong. You would want to do something with field and type so that if any of the applicationGateways are not equal to 0.0.0.0 then deny. For more information on defintion structure check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved as follow:

```
{
  "policyType": "Custom",
  "mode": "All",
  "displayName": "check_default_route_gateway_plus_default",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "count": {
        "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*]",
        "where": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*].nextHopIpAddress",
              "equals": "[parameters('DefaultGW')]"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*].name",
              "equals": "DEFAULT"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables/routes[*].addressPrefix",
              "equals": "0.0.0.0/0"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "notEquals": 1 
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "DefaultGW": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Default Gateway IP",
        "description": "The default Gateway IP. It correspond to the Proxy IP"
      },
      "defaultValue": "PUT_HERE_THE_IP_OF_YOUR_APPLIANCE"
    }
  }
}
```

This policy will fail in there is not a default route called `DEFAULT` with the addressPrefix `0.0.0.0/0` pointing to yours Appliance.

It took me sometime to arrive to it because the logic is contrary to my expected behavior.
The policy fire when its expression is evaluated to **true**, while I thought that it would have fired then evaluated to **false**.

A big help to achieve it, came from the VSCode plugin [Azure Policy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzurePolicy.azurepolicyextension) where you can test your policy interactively without waiting the cloud delay.

Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure can be useful to see all the policy constructs.